# Tracking app installs from a self hosted server Android

Tags: android

We are trying to track app installs for a self hosted android app using our own click tracking which is server 2 server.

What we do is create a tracking link which leads to the initiate the download and at the end of our download url generates a random subid/variable/no. to track each click.

What we need to do now is to collect this from the browser url and pass it back to our server from the app to be able to track what click generated the install for us.

Challenge here is we are not able to collect that subid generated on each click that leads to the app download to be able to post it back. Does anyone know how can we collect the Subid & post it back after the user installs and open the app?

Comment: Do you mean a html page produced by a php webserver which contains a link with a GET parameter subid?

Comment: Yes. The html page link itself contains the sub id as param

Comment: why cant you collect that parameter subid?

Comment: For the rest most of your scenario is unclear to me. I spent yesterday a lot of time understanding it and today I can start again. Please write down your scenario step by step first. Make it clearer what the app has to do and what the server has to do.